# Android - how to draw in a multiple view layout

Tags: android, view, draw

i have to draw a ball inside a view (or anything else that is good for this task).

I have followed some tutorial about the matter, but every tutorial that i have found
uses only one view (that is shown on the screen without the use of a layout).
But in my Activity i use a layout, that is composed by many views, and i want to draw 
only on one of them.

here a little [mockup](http://i42.tinypic.com/k0jytg.jpg)!

Anybody knows a way to do it?
Is the view the wrong container to do it?

Thanks is advance!

Bye

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extend a view that inherits from [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html). this kind of view lets you handle a view that contains other views. with that, you can control the drawing, measures and layout of each of it's children separately

Answer (score 0):

Your mockup can be made with a LinearLayout, which will contain some TextView's and you own View (the one which is containing the ball).

I'm surprised by this question, because there are many examples over the net explaining how to build a layout containing multiple views.